# How to persist LangChain conversation memory (save and load)?

Tags: python, pydantic, langchain, large-language-model

I'm creating a conversation like so:

```
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, model_name=OPENAI_DEFAULT_MODEL)
conversation = ConversationChain(llm=llm, memory=ConversationBufferMemory())
```

But what I really want is to be able to save and load that `ConversationBufferMemory()` so that it's persistent between sessions. There doesn't seem to be any obvious tutorials for this but I noticed "Pydantic" so I tried to do this:

```
saved_dict = conversation.memory.chat_memory.dict()
cm = ChatMessageHistory(**saved_dict) # or cm = ChatMessageHistory.parse_obj(saved_dict)
```

But this fails:

```
ValidationError: 6 validation errors for ChatMessageHistory
messages -> 0
  Can't instantiate abstract class BaseMessage with abstract method type (type=type_error)
```

Thoughts? I'd love links to any sort of guide, repo, reference, etc.

Comment: The problem I see is that the `dict()` output doesn't include class names so trying to reload it means that it can't see whether it's a `HumanMessage` or `AIMessage` so it just uses `BaseMessage` and fails

Comment: Does `conversation.memory.chat_memory.json()` include class names?

Comment: As an aside, this appears a langchain specific implementation of model serialization. (Pickling is probs best approach.)

Answer (score 9):

Rather than mess around too much with LangChain/Pydantic serialization issues, I decided to just use Pickle the whole thing and that worked fine:

```
pickled_str = pickle.dumps(conversation.memory)
conversation2 = ConversationChain(llm=llm, memory=pickle.loads(pickled_str)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. it works fine in interactive Python shell but when I save the commands to a .py file and run it no such luck. the file saves but with just the memory format no history of chat.

agent_chain = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent="conversational-react-description", memory=memory)

print(agent_chain.run(input='how many cars do i have?'))

filesv = open('Chat_mem_001.pkl', 'wb')

pickle.dump(agent_chain.memory, filesv)

filesv.close()

....
Any ideas why works fine in shell but not .py file run?

Comment: contains  unpickleable stuff it seems:
`TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object`

Answer (score 9):

I just did something similar, hopefully this will be helpful. On a high level:

1. use `ConversationBufferMemory` as the memory to pass to the Chain initialization

```py
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo-0301')
original_chain = ConversationChain(
    llm=llm,
    verbose=True,
    memory=ConversationBufferMemory()
)
original_chain.run('what do you know about Python in less than 10 words')
```

2. extract messages from memory in the form of `List[langchain.schema.HumanMessage|AIMessage]` (not serializable)

```py
extracted_messages = original_chain.memory.chat_memory.messages
```

3. transform the extracted message to serializable native Python objects

```py
ingest_to_db = messages_to_dict(extracted_messages)
```

4. perform db operations to write to and read from database of your choice, I'll just use `json.dumps` and `json.loads` to illustrate

```py
retrieve_from_db = json.loads(json.dumps(ingest_to_db))
```

5. transform the retrieved serialized object back to `List[langchain.schema.HumanMessage|AIMessage]`

```py
retrieved_messages = messages_from_dict(retrieve_from_db)
```

6. construct `ChatMessageHistory` from the messages

```py
retrieved_chat_history = ChatMessageHistory(messages=retrieved_messages)
```

7. construct `ConversationBufferMemory` from `ChatMessageHistory`

```py
retrieved_memory = ConversationBufferMemory(chat_memory=retrieved_chat_history)
```

8. pass memory back to the newly initiated Chain

```py
reloaded_chain = ConversationChain(
    llm=llm,
    verbose=True,
    memory=retrieved_memory
)
```

You can find the full code snippet at this [GitHub Link](https://github.com/ShumzZzZz/GPT-Rambling/blob/main/LangChain%20Specific/langchain_persist_conversation_memory.ipynb)

Comment: Could you please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77055206/langchain-getting-file-pydantic-main-py-line-341-in-pydantic-main-basemodel?noredirect=1#comment135842626_77055206

Comment: But that way you only get the messages dict, but not the summary memory buffer, right?

Answer (score 1):

if you built a full-stack app and want to save user's chat, you can have different approaches:

1- you could create a chat buffer memory for each user and save it on the server. but as the name says, this lives on memory, if your server instance restarted, you would lose all the saved data. so this is not a real persistence.

2- the real solution is to save all the chat history in a database. when the user is logged in and navigates to its chat page, it can retrieve the saved history with the chat ID. since your app is chatting with `open ai api`, you already set up a chain and this chain needs the message history. so once you retrieve the chat history from the database, you should be populating chat chain memory with this chat history.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using an SQL database to store your response and give a specific ID or Title to that conversation. Next time you want to query for the same conversation just give that ID or Title to SQL query retrieve the messages and load them to *memory* variable it could be ConversationBufferMemory().

I have done something similar in Django here is some code of it.

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}:{self.title}"

class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_response = models.TextField(null=True, default='')
    ai_response = models.TextField(null=True, default='')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.conversation}: {self.id}"
```

this help to create tables in sql db.

now we will see how to store messages and title in db:

```
def store_message(user_response, ai_response, conversation_id):
    ChatMessage.objects.create(
        user_response=user_response,
        ai_response=ai_response,
        conversation_id=conversation_id,
    )

def store_title(title, user):
    Conversation.objects.create(
        title=title,
        user=user
    )
```

Here is additional code to generate titles specific to your chats:

```
# API for title generator
API_URL = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/czearing/article-title-generator"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer YOUR_HF_TOKEN_FOR_ABOVE_API"}

def generate_title(payload):
    response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)
    return response.json()[0]['generated_text']
```

Here is the code to get conversations from the db and load it in the memory:
`

```
def retrieve_conversation(title, user):
    # number of conversations
    num_recent_conversations = 4
    # Retrieve the most recent conversation history from the database
    conversation_obj = Conversation.objects.get(title=title, user=user)
    conversation_id = getattr(conversation_obj, 'id')
    
    # Retrieve recent conversation messages
    conversation_context = ChatMessage.objects.filter(
        conversation_id=conversation_id
    ).order_by('-timestamp')[:num_recent_conversations:-1]
    
    # Storing the retrived data from db to model memory 
    lst = []
    for msg in conversation_context:
        input_msg = getattr(msg, 'user_response')
        output_msg = getattr(msg, 'ai_response')
        lst.append({"input": input_msg, "output": output_msg})
    
    for x in lst:
        inputs = {"input": x["input"]}
        outputs = {"output": x["output"]}
        memory.save_context(inputs, outputs)
    
       
    retrieved_chat_history = ChatMessageHistory(
        messages=memory.chat_memory.messages
    )
    
    return retrieved_chat_history
```

Now we will use this ChatMessageHistory to give context to older conversations in the model

Following is my request function in my Django views that Sums up the code:

```
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        request_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        prompt = request_data.get('prompt')
        user = request.user
        provided_title = request_data.get('title')
        if provided_title:
            # Create a ChatMessageHistory instance
            retrieved_chat_history = retrieve_conversation(
                provided_title, user)

        else:
            memory.clear()
            retrieved_chat_history = ChatMessageHistory(messages=[])

        reloaded_chain = ConversationChain(
            llm=llm,
            memory=ConversationBufferMemory(
                chat_memory=retrieved_chat_history),
            verbose=True
        )

        response = reloaded_chain.predict(input=prompt)

        if provided_title:
            title = provided_title
        else:
            # Generate a default title if not provided
            title = generate_title({
                "inputs": response
            })
            store_title(title, user)

        conversation_title = Conversation.objects.get(title=title, user=user)
        conversation_id = getattr(conversation_title, 'id')
        store_message(prompt, response, conversation_id)

        return JsonResponse({
            'ai_responce': response,
            'title':title
        }, status=201)
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Langchain recommends using Cassandradb for storing message history:
https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/memory/cassandra_chat_message_history

Answer (score 0):

you try
retrieve_from_db = json.loads(json.dumps(db_chain.memory.to_json()))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That doesn't work, a memory contains arbitrary classes as attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to shum's answer, following is a git showing saving and passing memory for ConversationSummaryBuffer type. Pickle directly does not work on it as it contains multithreads.

Logic:
Instead of pickling the whole memory object, we will simply pickle the memory.load_memory_variables({}) response.
Later one can load the pickle object, extract the summary and conversation then pass it to newly instantiated memory object using following function:

```
for item in extract_mem['chat_history']:
    if isinstance(item, SystemMessage):
       blank_memory.moving_summary_buffer = item.content
    elif isinstance(item, HumanMessage):
       blank_memory.chat_memory.add_user_message(item.content)
    elif isinstance(item, AIMessage):
       blank_memory.chat_memory.add_ai_message(item.content)
```

https://github.com/Sidhant1201/langchain_ConversationSummaryBufferMemory

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35479116)