# langchain: Getting File "pydantic/main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__ pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am using langchain with Open ai GPT-3.5. I am using agents to send user's queries to specific tools and I am getting output responses through my agent. Now I want the output response to be JSON but the final answer generated by Agent is String. I saw that Intermediate step has JSON value. So I added return_intermediate_steps=True in the agent.

I also have memory in the agent which stores human and AI outputs. Now I have defined memory like below:

```
memory = ConversationBufferMemory( output_key="intermediate_steps",return_messages=True)
```

So I was expecting it to store Intermediate steps output as Ai output in memory. But I ended up having the below error

> File "pydantic/main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.**init**
> pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for
> AIMessage content   str type expected (type=type_error.str)

My agent initialization is as below

```
agent1 = initialize_agent(tools=tools,llm=llm, agent=AgentType.CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION,memory=memory,return_intermediate_steps=True)
```

After reading the error, I think that it is caused because it is expecting the type of AI message as str but in my case, unfortunately, it is Json (I wouldn't mind if there's any way of making this JSON as str of JSON by accessing intermediate steps or any other approach). Now I don't want to make changes in the langchain's code, I am not even sure if I can do that by myself. So came here to see if anyone has any idea.
Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: could you share you code...

Comment: @ZKS Unfortunately, I cannot share the entire code, but have shared agent initialization. Agent sends the query to my tool and the tool generates a JSON output, now agent formats this output, but I want the tool's JSON as output, so I am trying to keep intermediate step as ai message in memory. Hope this gives a little clarity of flow. Thank you.